# Green's kernel estimates on finitely generated groups

Tags: reference-request, geometric-group-theory, harmonic-functions, green-function

I was reading a [paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/2006/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=263309%20and%20153585&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=2&mx-pid=1217561) by W. Hebisch and L. Saloff-Coste titled "Gaussian Estimates for Markov Chains and Random Walks on Groups"  where I came to know about certain bounds on convolution powers of probability measures and the associated Green kernel on polynomial growth groups. Interestingly, the paper exhibits  bounds for convolution powers of probability measures and their gradients on polynomial groups with volume growth of any order. However, for the case of the Green kernel such bounds are being proved only for groups with polynomial growth of order more than 2 (Theorem 5.1 of the paper).

I am curious whether there are Green kernel bounds for groups of polynomial growth of order atmost 2.  If such results do not exist, are there any intuitive/heuristic reasons that indicate that such bounds cannot actually be expected ?

Answer (score 5):

Symmetric random walks on finitely generated groups of growth at most quadratic are recurrent, therefore the Green kernel
$$ \Theta(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}p^{(n)}(x)$$
is infinite for all $x$. (The right-hand side can be interpreted as the expected number of visits to $x$.) I guess the gradient estimate still holds for $D=2$, but fails for $D=0,1$ for the same reasons.

Comment: @CoretinB: Nice answer! May I ask a quick question on a related theme? I am trying to understand Corollary 25.10 (page 268) in Woess's [Book][1] "Random Walks on Infinite Graphs and Groups", which says that graphs with polynomial growth having a quasi-transitive random walk have weak Liouville property, and with some extra assumptions on the probability measure the graph also has strong Liouville property.  Is "quasi-transitive random walk" related to the transience of the random walk?            

[1]: http://math.bme.hu/~gabor/oktatas/SztoM/Woess.RWonInfinGrGp.pdf

Comment: @piper1967 No, it has to do with the symmetries of the underlying graph and the transition probabilities, this notion of “quasi-transitive” random walk is defined page 13-14 of Woess.